# Why is this ruby test failing?

Tags: ruby

I am doing some of the kata challenges on codewars:

> This is the challenge: An *isogram* is a word that has no repeating letters, consecutive or non-consecutive. Implement a function that determines whether a string that contains only letters is an isogram. Assume the empty string is an isogram. Ignore letter case.

I have the following piece of code:

```
def is_isogram(string)
  string.downcase!
  ('a'..'z').each do |letter|
    return string.count(letter) <= 1 || string.length == 0 ? true : false
  end
end
```

with the following tests:

```
Test.assert_equals(is_isogram("Dermatoglyphics"), true )
Test.assert_equals(is_isogram("isogram"), true )
Test.assert_equals(is_isogram("aba"), false, "same chars may not be adjacent" )
Test.assert_equals(is_isogram("moOse"), false, "same chars may not be same case" )
Test.assert_equals(is_isogram("isIsogram"), false )
Test.assert_equals(is_isogram(""), true, "an empty string is a valid isogram" )
```

My code fails on the fourth test. Could someone please shed some light on what I am doing wrong and how I can get the test to pass?

Comment: `string.length == 0 ? true : false` ??

Comment: Modifying external state in a predicate method? Terrible, terrible idea! (hint: use `downcase`, not `downcase!`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning from the method at the end of the first iteration. Thus, your code has nothing to do with isogram. Your code will check whether the first character in the range (i.e., `"a"`) is repeated or not.

The first two examples only have one `"a"`, so they return `true`. The third has more than one `"a"`, so it returns `false`. The fourth has no `"a"`, so it returns `true`.

To get your code to work, change it to:

```
def is_isogram(string)
  string.downcase!
  ('a'..'z').each do |letter|
    return false if string.count(letter) > 1
  end
  return true
end
```

But a more Rubyish way to write it is:

```
def is_isogram(string)
  string = string.downcase
  ('a'..'z').none?{|letter| string.count(letter) > 1}
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I came up with my own solution using what you have said, your solution is better. But now I understand where I was going wrong

Comment: A bit slower but more ruby-ish one-liner: `str.downcase.chars.group_by(&:itself).all?{|_, vals| vals.length == 1}` :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 def is_isogram(string)
  string.downcase.chars.uniq == string.downcase.chars
 end
```